# RestSharp Request.AddFile parameter order

Tags: c#, rest, restsharp

I'm trying to do a POST with a CSV file to a REST endpoint using RestSharp. However, after some extensive tinkering, I've found that the receiving server is picky about the order of the headers in the request body. I need to ensure that after the multi-part form boundary the first thing that appears is the content-disposition. It actually doesn't even need the Content-Type but RestSharp insists on adding it no matter what I do. So I need to force RestSharp to not add the Content-Type, or add it after the Content-Disposition.

It's doing this:

```
Content-Type: multipart/form-data; boundary="196f530b-7398-43b5-ab7e-f98bd956425a"
Content-Length: 2476
Expect: 100-continue
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate
Connection: Keep-Alive

--196f530b-7398-43b5-ab7e-f98bd956425a
Content-Type: text/csv
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="File"; filename="e54bf33c-28cc-4f1e-9cb1-8d2b37a7906b.csv"

"My","CSV","ETC"
```

I need it to do this:

```
Content-Type: multipart/form-data; boundary="196f530b-7398-43b5-ab7e-f98bd956425a"
Content-Length: 2476
Expect: 100-continue
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate
Connection: Keep-Alive

--196f530b-7398-43b5-ab7e-f98bd956425a
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="File"; filename="e54bf33c-28cc-4f1e-9cb1-8d2b37a7906b.csv"
Content-Type: text/csv

"My","CSV","ETC"
```

Notice how the content-disposition comes directly after the form boundary. I don't think I had this issue in an older version of RestSharp, but now I do.

Comment: There's an issue in RestSharp repository about the ability to remove the content type header from multipart data from requests. It wasn't discussed with regards to files, so feel free to add your thoughts there. RestSharp doesn't control the order of headers as it uses the .NET `MultipartFormDataContent` and just assigns header values for parameters of the content object (`StreamContent` in this case). The request is valid though, the order of headers should not matter.

Comment: Unfortunately the order of the headers does matter to this third party API... I agree it probably shouldn't but I have no control to change that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So I had to do it manually to control the order of the headers in the body. Here's the code I used if it helps someone else:

```
oRequest.AddHeader("Content-Type", "multipart/form-data; boundary=X-FILE-BOUNDARY");

var sbBody = new System.Text.StringBuilder();
sbBody.AppendLine("--X-FILE-BOUNDARY");
sbBody.AppendLine("Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"File\"; filename=\"" + System.IO.Path.GetFileName(strFileName) + "\"");
sbBody.AppendLine("Content-Type: text/csv");
sbBody.AppendLine();
sbBody.AppendLine(System.IO.File.ReadAllText(strFileName));
sbBody.AppendLine("--X-FILE-BOUNDARY--");

oRequest.AddParameter("multipart/form-data", sbBody.ToString(), ParameterType.RequestBody);
```